# невозможно распаковать неитерируемый объект int

Tags: python

```
# Инизиализировать словарь пустым списком для идентификатора каждого пользователя
friendships = {user["id"]: [] for user in users}
# И перебрать все дружеские пары, заполняя их:
for i, j in friendships:
    friendships[i].append(j) # Добавить j как друга для i
    friendships[j].append(i) # Добавить i как друга для j
```

Выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object.

Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Если `user["id"]` это числа, значит итерация по словарю `friendships` тоже будет давать числа, а пытаться разложить число на две переменные `i` и `j` звучит как бред

Answer (score 3):

Итерация по самому словарю - это итерация по его ключам. Проверьте сами:

```
sample = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
for i in sample:
    print(i)
```

В выводе у нас будет:

```
a
b
c
```

В python также есть разложение:

```
x = [1, 2]
a, b = x
```

Соответственно, выполнение кода `for i, j in friendships` ожидает, что единицы итерации будут разложены на i и j.

Это сработало бы, если, например, ключами в нашем словаре были кортежи (tuple)*:

```
z = {(1,2):'привет', (3,4):'ромашки'}
for i,j in z:
    print(f"{i=}, {j=}")
```

Но в нашем словаре `friendships` ключи - `int`-ы. Итерация `for i, j in friendships` на практике пытается сделать: `i, j = 1`. Из-за чего и появляется `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`.

---

Таким образом вам надо понять, как правильно пройтись по вашим данным, чтобы разложить их так, как вы хотите.

У встроенных словарей есть несколько методов, дающий легкий доступ к разным итерациям: по ключам - [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), по значениям - [`.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), по парам ключ-значение - [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Обратитесь к документации, посмотрите методы встроенных типов данных (list, str, dict, tuple, set и др.) - это обогатит ваше понимание того, как вы можете управлять объектами и что вы можете с ними делать.

---

* ключами словаря могут быть любые [хешируемые](https://docs.python.org/3.11/glossary.html#term-hashable) объекты.